# Restore or Overwrite existing SQL Server DB in AWS RDS using .BAK File from AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, restore

Is it is possible to Restore or Overwrite existing SQL Server DB in AWS RDS using .BAK File from AWS S3 Bucket?

ERROR:

Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database, Line 162 [Batch Start Line 2]
Database 'USERDB' already exists. Two databases that differ only by case or accent are not allowed. Choose a different database name.

Thanks!
S

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can restore from .bak file. Run the below amazon procedure in master DB through SSMS to restore from S3 bucket.

```
    exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database 
    @restore_db_name='Database_unique_name_tobe_created', 
    @s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::your-s3/Old_Database.bak' 

-- @restore_db_name – The name of the database to restore. Database names are unique. You can't restore a database with the same name as an existing database.
-- @s3_arn_to_restore_from = Backup file S3 bucket path
```

Refer:- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html

Comment: OP wants to restore to an existing db, this restores as a fresh db